# Execution order of return and out parameters

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Could someone please explain why following program will output "4,6" instead of "4,4".

```
MainProgram()
{
  int x = 2;
  int y = 0;

  parse(4, out y);
  Console.Write(y + ",");
  y = y + parse(x, out y);
  Console.Write(y);
}

int parse(int x, out int y)
{
    y = x;
    return y;
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: FYI - Eric Lippert has a nice post about this exact issue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx  (Look at the "Order of evaluation" section)

Comment: Why are you writing code this crazy in the first place?

Comment: I think you'd do better to explain why it is that you think that 4,4 is a sensible output, and then we can point out your mistake. Somewhere your chain of reasoning is going wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're really interested in the second call to `parse`, right?

The operands of `+` are evaluated from left to right, then the addition takes place, then the final assignment takes place.

This line:

```
y = y + parse(x, out y);
```

is logically:

```
int lhs = y;
// Now lhs = 4, x = 2, y = 4
int rhs = parse(x, out y);
// Now rhs = 2, x = 2, y = 2
y = lhs + rhs;
// Now y = 6
```

Does that help you?

Answer (score 1):

In the expression `y + parse(x, out y)` the value of y before the call to parse is captured as part of expression evaluation, then parse(x, out y) is called which modifies the value of y after the fact.  So the expression evaluates as `4 + 2`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem here. First 4 is assigned to y. Then the 2 from the return value of parse() is added to it. The result 6 is finally assigned to again y.
First, y before "+" is evaluated (4) and then parse() after "+" is evaluated (2), finally 4+2 is assigned to y.